# Update primefaces growl from inside ui:component

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have a page where the form contains a primefaces growl, and when adding message, and updating works very well, shows up and then dissappears as I wanted.

I added templating to some of my pages and I have placed the growl in a seperate form inside the main layout file, so it can be used and updated from every page using that template. However, though I try to add the message and update the growl it never shows up. Though in the response I see that the update was recivied from the server as following:

```
<partial-response><changes><update id="growlForm:growl">
<![CDATA[<span id="growlForm:growl"></span>
 <script id="growlForm:growl_s" type="text/javascript">
$(function(){PrimeFaces.cw('Growl','widget_growlForm_growl',
 {id:'growlForm:growl',sticky:true,life:6000,escape:true,msgs:
  [{summary:"Validation error!",detail:"Please check you input values.",severity:'error'}]});});
  </script>]]>
 </update>..... more changes
```

Pretty much the only issue is that the growl does not actually show up. It might not be even anything to do with jsf templating, but I figured since it worked on the other page it must be it because i use the same methods and everything.

The template system I use:

Common layout:

```
<h:head>
    <h:outputStylesheet name="style.css" library="css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../resources/js/common.js"></script>
    <title><ui:insert name="title"></ui:insert></title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:form id="growlForm">
        <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" sticky="true" />
    </h:form>
    <div id="page">
        <div id="header">
            <ui:insert name="header">
                <ui:include src="/restricted/templates/commonHeader.xhtml" />
            </ui:insert>
        </div>

        <div id="content">
            <ui:insert name="content">
            </ui:insert>
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
            <ui:insert name="footer">
                <ui:include src="/restricted/templates/commonFooter.xhtml" />
            </ui:insert>
        </div>

    </div>

</h:body>
```

Actual form ui part:

```
<ui:define name="content">
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                update();
            });
        </script>
        <h:form id="invoiceForm" styleClass="defaultForm">
            <div class="defaultPanel">

                //.. irrelevant content

                <span class="block"> <p:commandButton id="submitButton"
                        actionListener="#{invoiceBean.submit}"
                        value="#{msg.button_label_submit}" update=":invoiceForm :growlForm:growl"
                        oncomplete="update()" />
                </span>
            </div>
        </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

Can anyone please help me how can I get the growl to show up?

EDIT

Someone asked to post the code of the "update()" function but it does nothing really ust updates some input values based on other and it is in test phase i tried to rename it , still growl will not show.

```
function update() {
    // document.getElementById("total_price_amount").value = toFixed(ish *
    // 1.2,2);
    var sumNet = 0;
    var sumTax = 0;
    var sumTotal = 0;

    var selectvat = document.getElementById("invoiceForm:vat");
    var label = selectvat.options[selectvat.selectedIndex].text;
    var valueAsText = label.substring(0, label.length - 1);
    var valueAsInt = parseInt(valueAsText);

    var defaultTax = valueAsInt / 100;
    $("[id$='articleItemReference']")
            .each(
                    function() {
                        var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
                        var prefix = currentId.replace('articleItemReference',
                                '');
                        var quantity = document.getElementById(prefix
                                + 'quantity').value;
                        var price = document.getElementById(prefix + 'price').value;
                        // set price incl vat
                        var priceIncl = toFixed((1 + defaultTax) * price);
                        document.getElementById(prefix + 'priceInclVAT').value = priceIncl;
                        var discountAmount = document.getElementById(prefix
                                + 'discount').value;
                        var discountType = document.getElementById(prefix
                                + 'discountType').value;

                        var totalPrice = price * quantity;
                        var totalPriceWithDiscount;
                        if (discountType == 'percent') {
                            totalPriceWithDiscount = totalPrice
                                    * ((100 - discountAmount) / 100);
                        } else {
                            totalPriceWithDiscount = totalPrice
                                    - discountAmount;
                        }

                        document.getElementById(prefix + 'sum').value = toFixed(
                                totalPriceWithDiscount, 2);

                        var tax = totalPriceWithDiscount * defaultTax;

                        sumNet = sumNet + totalPriceWithDiscount;
                        sumTax = sumTax + tax;
                        sumTotal = sumTotal + (totalPriceWithDiscount + tax);
                    });
    document.getElementById("invoiceForm:sumOfAll").innerHTML = toFixed(
            sumTotal, 2);
    document.getElementById("invoiceForm:sumOfTax").innerHTML = toFixed(sumTax,
            2);
    document.getElementById("invoiceForm:sumOfNet").innerHTML = toFixed(sumNet,
            2);
}
```

Comment: where is the definition of update() function? it IS relevant

Comment: Try to put a growl in the form inside content and check whether it is working or not

Comment: I have already tried it it does not work, update info is still in response though.